# setState(..., callback) calls callback before state has been set

Tags: reactjs

I commonly write code like this (for re-use):

```
function doSomething() {
  // I do something with this.state.MyVar
}

function buttonClicked(e) {
  this.setState({MyVar: e.target.value}, this.doSomething());
}

function otherEvent(e) {
  this.setState({MyVar: e.target.value}, this.doSomething());
}
```

Once doSomething() is called, it is not uncommon for the value to be different from that of e.target.value. It seems as though the callback does not actually occur *after* the state has been updated?

Note, this always works:

```
function doSomething(value) {
  // I do something with value
}

function buttonClicked(e) {
  this.setState({MyVar: e.target.value});
  this.doSomething(e.target.value);
}
```

This is in Google Chrome, and with latest version of ReactJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the parentheses as they immediately execute the function and pass the resolved value (return value) as the callback - which is not desired. The callback must be a function *reference* not invocation, because the callback is internally invoked. Using parentheses, and thus consequently invoking the function it will give the illusion of executing immediately:

```
this.setState({MyVar: e.target.value}, doSomething);
//                                                ^^ No parens!
```

This way, `doSomething`'s reference is passed instead of an invocation, and it will execute accordingly.

---

Examples of these kinds of problems can be seen in many cases. Consider this snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", foo()); //to demonstrate the common mistake, let's try with parentheses

function foo() {
  console.log("I've been clicked (but not really!)"); 
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Click me!</button>
```

You can see that we are adding a listener to button `#test`, and it seems that we are setting `foo` as the event handler, but in actuality it executes immediately, even though we have not clicked it! This is because when the JavaScript is run, `foo()` is immediately executed, thus logging `I've been clicked (but not really!)` before it should. Since the function returns nothing, it's equivalent to:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", undefined);
```

`undefined` is passed as the event handler because the resolved value is passed as the event handler, and since the function returned nothing, it was `undefined`.

This can be applied here because when you pass a invocation for a callback, you are actually passing the return value of that function, because you *invoke* it. To combat this you need to *pass a reference*.

Comment: @Jay The callback is executed, so a function *reference* is needed. When you immediately invoke it, you are trying to do: `<return value>();`

Comment: What if I wrap my calls, so that I can keep the parameters?

this.setState({MyVar: "hello"}, function() { myFunction("a", "b", "hello"); });

Comment: You are too quick! I accidentally posted, thinking enter would give me a new line ;)

Comment: @Jay In that case parentheses can be kept, because you are passing a function reference (the function itself). You may also use [arrow functions in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `() => myFunction("a", "b", "hello")` or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): `myFunction.bind(<thisArg>, "a", "b", "hello")` for binding `this` and other arguments